# Which verse of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa is Devdutt Pattanaik referring to?

Tags: ramayana, rama, identification-request, sita

[This](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/devdutt-pattanaik-modern-people-want-to-feel-liberal-so-they-construct-a-past-thats-conservative-5420504/) Indian Express article quotes Devdutt Pattanaik as saying:

> On tradition vs modernity
>
> Modern people invent tradition. Because modern people want to feel “liberal” and “modern”, they will construct a past that is conservative. And you see that in writings all the time. So Sita has to be this creature who has no voice of her own. But when you actually read the Valmiki Ramayana, you'll be like, 'this lady seems to have a voice'. **In fact, there's a dialogue where Ram says, "Whenever I ask her to do anything, she says no."**

Which verse of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa is Pattanaik referring to?

Comment: Lol what is opinion based here?

Comment: How is this question opinion based?

Comment: @Rickross An objective question with 'identification-request' tag closed as opinion-based. Ha Ha!

Comment: @TheDestroyer If that is not opinion based, you can just reopen the question.

Comment: @Rickross, @ TheDestroyer - lol if you think this is not opinion based. tomorrow i can make a claim 'Lakshmana is Rama's elder brother', put it in an article, then cite it and ask a question 'Which verse of Valmiki Ramayana states that Lakshmana is older to Rama'. Devdutt Patnaik has been known to not read scriptures yet make random claims about it. sv acts as if he is unbiased and objective. If he was really objective, he should just ask 'Does Valmiki Ramayana have this verse', instead of asking 'Which verse is he referring to'. Just tagging it as identification-request does not remove bias.

Comment: instead of asking 'Which verse is he referring to'  --  It is the same thing because we can answer by refuting also. If no such verse is found in the text then that is the answer (although I understand it is difficult to prove that something is not there somewhere). And if  verses like that are actually present then that makes answering easier. But from whr did this relying on opinions come into the picture? This a factual/objective question. No scope of speculation here. @ram

Comment: @Rickross, if OP knows that the person (devdutt patnaik) they're quoting is known to be unreliable and purposely says random stuff (see similar question about manu smriti vaisya/sudra), then choosing to quote that person and especially picking out quotes that suit 'modern sensibility' - that's definitely biased. Any question can be converted to a 'factual' question like this - *"The paper Atheist Daily quotes Mr. Loudmouth as saying 'If you read Linga Purana, you'll see that Shiva says 'Vedas are just made up by Brahmins to keep others down' '. Which verse is Mr. Loudmouth referring to?"*

Comment: @Rickross, even if it turns out that fellow and OP are correct in pointing the verse, this is a pattern - this is the 3rd time OP has quoted devdutt and asking us to find out scriptural basis for it. That too, not with innocent curiosity, but with hidden agenda. If OP is really UN-opinionated, he would ask 'Does such a verse exist', not 'Which verse number is this'. It will be very easy to flood this site with quotes from random atheist articles and convert them to 'factual' questions about scripture. 'Which verse from Bhagavatam says there is no Bhagavan?'

Comment: I can see that u hv problems with Devdutta P and this question but for that u can downvote the question (which I think u hv already done) and move on. As I hv said this is quite clearly not close-able (at least not as opinion-based). @ram

Comment: @TheDestroyer, whichever mod reopened this question, also reopen [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/quoting-random-persons-opinion-reference-about-scriptures), or go to discussion [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/quoting-random-persons-opinion-reference-about-scriptures)

Comment: @ram No mod reopened this question. Users reopened this question.

Answer (score 3):

> But when you actually read the Valmiki Ramayana, you'll be like, 'this lady seems to have a voice'.

This might be referring to 5 Sargas of **Valmiki Ramayana: Ayodhya Kanda** where Rama asks her to stay in Ayodhya but she insists going with Rama in forest:

- [Sarga 26](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga26/ayodhya_26_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 27](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga27/ayodhya_27_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 28](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga28/ayodhya_28_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 29](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga29/ayodhya_29_frame.htm)
- [Sarga 30](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga30/ayodhya_30_frame.htm)

---

> In fact, there's a dialogue where Ram says, "Whenever I ask her to do anything, she says no."

This might be some opinion based interpretation of the below partial verse:

> कारणैः बहुभिस् तथ्यैः वार्यमाणौ न च इच्चतः || [2.34.23](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/content?language=dv&field_kanda_tid=2&field_sarga_value=34&field_sloka_value=23)
>
> [Lord Rama to his father:] I tried to dissuade them (Lakshmana and Sita) with a number of reasons but they did not agree.

When we read this verse stand alone, this comes out like mentioned in the question but when we read it with context (after reading previous Sargas), we understand that it's not like Lakshmana and Seetha didn't agree to what Rama says but out of devotion and love they insisted to going in forest with Rama putting their comfort aside.

Comment: "Whenever I ask her to do anything, she says no." and what actual quote says.. What a difference!! Even if you read it stand alone, it doesn't look like Sita is disuadding with Rama. See the word anything in the question. That looks like very bad interpretation to show something else which is not intended by Valmiki.