# Which scripture is Zakir Naik referring to here?

Tags: identification-request, upanishads

In his website, Zakir Naik claims that the name Allah appears in Upanishads:

> "Allah" in Rigveda Book 2 Hymn I verse II
>   Even in the Rigveda which is
>   the most sacred scripture of the Hindus, one of the attributes given
>   to God Almighty in Book no 2 Hymn no I verse II, is ‘Ila’ which if
>   pronounced properly is the same as Allah.
>
> "Allo Upanishad":
>   Amongst the various Upanishads one of the Upanishad
>   is named as ‘Allo’ Upanishad in which God is referred to as "Allah"
>   several times.

Which verse and upanishad is he referring to ?

Comment: This is oldest Upnishad of all time which directly jumped from sky to a human hand, that human was noone but Zakir Naik only. @ram

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, I recently had divine revelation called QURAM, where all instances of Allah are replaced with Ram.

Comment: :D @ram But seriously Man! You're better than this; I mean don't ask such question. It doesn't add any value to the site.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, this is only to bring attention to similar 'opinionated' questions by another user. basically quoting some random guy and asking if there is scriptural basis for it. see comment chain here : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29924/which-verse-of-v%c4%81lm%c4%abki-r%c4%81m%c4%81ya%e1%b9%87a-is-devdutt-pattanaik-referring-to#comment91003_29924

Comment: I see! So that's how it got started, and you asked chain of questions like that: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29952/647 which got answered too.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, in my opinion, the definition of opinion-based should include the opinions of the person being quoted in the question, in addition to the opinion of the OP. user sv asked 3 questions quoting Devdutt Patnaik, who we already proved does not read scriptures, or tries to misinterpret them. Mods think that just because OP is asking 'do scriptures have these verses', that OP is just innocently curious without an agenda.

Comment: @ram Please don't just ask some questions like this. Just ask if you want to know an answer a question or you want to share the knowledge you have by asking and answering it. I think you are ask better than this. Some people just talk what they want to. Meta is the better place to raise a concern about opinion based questions. People who know what's opinion based or not can say there (perhaps Community Managers too).

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto here is the copy of Allopanishad https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Allopanishad_in_Satyarth_Prakash.pdf

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, i'm sure these questions will be deleted in a couple of days, but I want to draw attention to other users too, not just mods. if sv can bombard the site by referring to random articles and youtube videos (just go through his list of questions), and claim that he is simply being 'factual', so can others, and it trashes the site quality.

Comment: I said Community managers (They are the highest moderators on SE). These questions don't got deleted. Because there are people who vote to balance the downvotes any type of low quality question and may write answers too. If there are questions with positive score, it won't be deleted. Moreover, asking low quality questions will affect your profile and reputation (not only score) too.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, "affect your reputation" - that is exactly what I'm aiming for. affecting the reputation of users who ask questions that are obviously opinionated but hiding behind 'objectivity'.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda talks about the 'Allo Upanishad' in his Complete Works. He says that it is a 'Upanishad' written by a Muslim to try and justify the Muslim religion to Hindus.

Comment: @ram I think you should ask reference from vedas only

Comment: @Sarvabhouma,  i've posted a question in meta - you can take a look if interested https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/quoting-random-persons-opinion-reference-about-scriptures

Comment: Useless post...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, i know, it is just to bring attention to the type of questions that we're seeing on this site - https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/quoting-random-persons-opinion-reference-about-scriptures

Comment: @Pandya, this is getting silly.. we are not allowed to call a muslim, who proudly identifies himself as a muslim, a muslim ? By that logic, all questions or answers which refer to anyone has a Advaiti, or a Hindu, or a Iyer - must all be edited out because it is referring to their personal religion/belief/character.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto It adds value to this site. People can realize that it is not original and who knows some use this tactics to convert people from Hinduism to other religion. And this question thus proves that these tactics are fake and there is no such verse in Hinduism.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can get 1908 edition.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Allopanishad_in_Satyarth_Prakash.pdf

English Translation:

> I take refuge in our Allah [La, to perish, and alla, eternal] who
>   protects Mitra [sun] and Varuna [the god of water]. There is but one
>   God [Illelle]; the king, Varuna, again takes refuge (in him).
>   Everything is God; sun and stars. Everything is God; Varuna, the Sun,
>   the illuminator. The Great Breath, the Lord, is the Sacrificer. The
>   Lord is the Sacrificer. Allah is the first and best, the highest;
>   Omnipresent; Highest of all Gods. He is only One; ever remaining. By
>   sacrifice is Allah to be propitiated. Allah is sun, moon and all
>   stars. Allah is (the God) of Rishis and all other deities, and of
>   Indra, the first Maya [primordial matter] and the ether. Allah is in
>   the earth and in heaven and in multifarious forms. Everything is
>   Allah. Everything is Allah and everything is He. Om is Allah.
>   Everything is He. By nature eternal. Atharvan [the Rishi] bows down to
>   such. Give us water, cattle, siddhis, and things that live in water,
>   and Phut [a mantra]. The Slayer of enemies. Hum, Hrim. Nothing but
>   Allah; nothing but Allah.

Comment: This is great. We can distribute it in Kashmir and unite India & Pakistan.

Comment: It is of course a fake Upanishad. Akbar ordered a converted Brahmin to write Allopanishad. This book was then fraudulently inserted in genuine copies of Atharva Veda. Until early 20th century, many Atharvaveda manuscripts had Allopanishad. Akbar's dirty trick almost succeeded. Many manuscripts of Atharvaveda carried Allopanishad until 20th century.. It also had a chapter proclaiming the supremacy of Allah and the religion of Islam. Swami Dayananda Saraswati started the movement to purge Allopanishad. This fraudulent Allopanishad was promoted by Gandhi who certified it as one of 108 Upanishads

Comment: I am too scared to even click on the link.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, i've posted a question in meta - you can take a look if interested https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1489/quoting-random-persons-opinion-reference-about-scriptures

Comment: @RaRa you could add your comment in your answer which proves that this is just a fake verse added. So that both question and answer can become comeplete.

Answer (score 0):

Allo upnishad is a fake upanishad created by islamic invaders of india to misguide believers of Sanatana dharma and give them positive impression about Islam; during Akbar's time he made brahmins in his kingdom to write a upnishad to praise and confuse followers of Real Vedhas and Upnishads, check the details here : https://indictales.com/2019/12/03/allopanishad-written-under-the-patronage-of-akbar-is-not-a-genuine-upanishad/

Comment: Links are fabricated. Upanishads contain many slokas when recited with concentration yield good benefits to human.

Comment: How does that prove authenticity of allopnishadh ? While Upnishads are way  way before Islam and so alla came in to being?